# Configuration error with Tomcat. System doesn't recognize path

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I can't seem to get past this Catalina error. There must be something wrong with my configuration but I can't figure out what it is. When I try to run this program from the command line, I get "The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly". When I try to run in eclipse the Catalina error prevents server startup. When I try to switch locations and point directly at CATALINA_HOME I get this error:

```
Publishing the configuration...
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\context.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\server.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\tomcat-users.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/backup\web.xml: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\backup\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I get the same error when I use the radio button to point to CATALINA_HOME in the server overview window.

A partial boot log produces these errors:

```
Mar 07, 2017 11:15:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I tried to reconfigure Tomcat using tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt without any difference in results.

Here are my environment settings:

CATALINA_BASE = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11

CATALINA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11

CLASS_PATH = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\lib\servlet-api.jar;
             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;
             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\lib;.

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, so this may be a stupid question, but why do the paths in your first block have both `/` and `\\` in them? Does that matter?

Comment: I saw that as well.  I went to that location. There is no backup file. The actual environment variables aren't set that way.